# Посоветуйте книгу либо ресурс

Tags: php, книги

В общем, есть задание диплома по написанию собственного файлового менеджера на php. Php знаю поверхностно, хотелось бы узнать от опытных, где я могу подтянуть свои знания в работе с файлами на php.

Comment: Файловый менеджер не через сторонний апи, а просто файлы на серваке смотреть? Проще простого, подойдет любой учебник с основами пхп. Советую присмотреться к издательству [o'reilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/category/browse-subjects/programming/php.do)  и их соответствующим книгам по php. Есть переведенные на русский, широко известные, в магазинах любого города должны быть.

Comment: [Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/refs.fileprocess.file.php) в помощь, там много примером в все довольно ясно

Comment: @VostokSisters Дословно с переводом на русский "Разработать модуль "файловый менеджер" на базе фреймворку yii 2 . Я так понимаю, документации на php.net мне хватит?

Comment: @StepaDemchenko, про этот фреймверк я не знаю. Но то, что я посоветовал + документации по этому фреймверку должно хватить.